# ScrollTop depois que a página já foi carregada

Tags: jquery

Quero fazer scrollTop depois que eu clico em um botão. Só que não na página que estou e sim na página que irá abrir.

Meu HTML:

```
<a href="/clinicas" class="saibaMais cp margin-top-40 margin-bottom-25 f-left unidadesClick">
    <div class="saibaMaisText">saiba mais</div>
    <div class="saibaMaisHover">saiba mais</div>
</a>
```

E meu Jquery:

```
$('.unidadesClick').click(function () {
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
   scrollTop: '620px'
   }, 700);
});
```

Do jeito que está, ele faz o ScrollTop na mesma página. Como faço para isso ter efeito quando eu estiver dentro do `a` **/clinicas**?

Comment: Tipo uma `#ancora`?

Comment: Não. Quando eu clico no `a`, ele abre a página e dá um ScrollTop.

Comment: Ah, tipo uma `#ancora` com a rolagem suave?

Comment: Isso, pode ser sim. O que acontece é que tá dando scroll na página antes de acessar o `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique se você está acessando uma URL que contenha `/clinicas`:

```
$(function(){
    //coloque este código onde quer que você tenha o código que verifica que o DOM está pronto
    if (window.location.toString().indexOf('/clinicas') > 0) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
             scrollTop: '620px'
        }, 700);
    }

});
```

Isso já deve resolver o seu problema.

O seu jQuery está dando scroll na página antes de acessar pois é o que está escrito: ao clicar no elemento `.unidadesClick`, scrollTop nos 620px do `<body>`, quando o que você quer é que dê scroll quando estivermos na página `/clinicas`.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava! :D